# Bridging http request with path variable in CAMEL REST

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I am trying to bridge Camel REST endpoints to a backend server. Corresponding REST DSL is as follows:

```
    from("rest:get:tt:/{id}")
    .toF("%s/%s?bridgeEndpoint=true","http://192.168.1.1:80","jjjj/llll/pppp/{id}");
```

My expectation is that the request should be forwarded to  `http://192.168.1.1:80/jjjj/llll/pppp/id` But what actually happens is that the request gets forwarded to `http://192.168.1.1:80/jjjj/llll/pppp/%7Bid%7D/tt/id`

Can any one suggest, what am I doing wrong and how I can achieve the desired behaviour? I am using Spring Boot Camel 2.3.4 which uses Camel 3.5.0 internally.

Answer (score 0):

Mean while, I have found a work around that to use .to() instead of .toF(). With .to(), I achieved desired behavior. Camel route DSL is Something like

```
 from("rest:get:tt:/{id}").to("rest:get:jjjj/llll/pppp/{id}?host=http://192.168.1.1:80")
```

But question still remains open that why it is not working with .toF().

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're using `{id}` syntax for `http` component uri, but I think it's only recognized by the `rest` component, so instead of having:

```
from("rest:get:tt:/{id}")
    .toF("%s/%s?bridgeEndpoint=true", "http://192.168.1.1:80", "jjjj/llll/pppp/{id}");
```

you could try using dynamic endpoint `.toD()` with simple expression `${header.id}`:

```
from("rest:get:tt:/{id}")
    .toD("http://192.168.1.1:80/jjjj/llll/pppp/${header.id}?bridgeEndpoint=true");
```

Not exactly sure if that's what you're aiming for though